# Deleted a secondary partition server 2008, Now Domain Controller wont boot?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

I had C: for OS.. D: for data.. but this Data partition was last modified "2016".. I made a full backup of it just to be safe but after rebooting post deletion this morning, I get the blue screen referring to Directory Services cannot start due to the following : file not found..

Scoured the edges of the internet to find out its most likely a file called ntds.dit corruption, however i tried the NTDS util and Emurepar and it did not work for me like all the others who said it instantly fixed their issues..

I do have a secondary Domain controller that seems to be working as long as I tell other users to modify DNS to point to it instead of primary that is not working but that tells me some form of replication is off and i really don't want to do anything other than get this original server back up and running for now..

Any ideas?? again I do have a system state backup, and also a file level backup. However the system state wants to recover to the D: partition again within a folder called D:\windows\NTDS but its only one file and why on earth would the machine use D: when C: is the OS and X: is the system recovery??

Answer (score 3):

Question: Why would you delete the volume in the first place? What purpose did that serve?

The AD database (Ntds.dit) was probably on the D: volume because some admins choose to put it on a separate volume from Windows. Doing that also happens to be a Microsoft best practice.

If you can't recover the volume then just build a new DC and manually remove this one from AD. Configure your domain clients to use both DC's for DNS, assuming the DC's are also the DNS servers for the AD domain.